# how to make mybatis insert uncertain table and columns

Tags: sql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

what I want is just like

```
 insert into  #{tableName} (#{tableColumn1}, ...) values (#{value1}, ... )
```

in mapper.xml

if I but it went wrong even through I set

```
statementType="STATEMENT"
```

how can I make it ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I've get the key,

when using #{} it'll be "prepared" if you want use dynamic table name and table columns u need use ${}

e.g

```
    INSERT INTO
        ${tableName}
    <foreach collection="columns" item="column" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
        ${column} 
    </foreach>          
        VALUES
    <foreach collection="values" item="value"  open="(" close=")" separator=",">
        '${value}'
    </foreach>
```

If anyone have same question I hope it'll be useful!